# Why does Doxygen documentation only appear for the last of multiple adjacent groups?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to document several similar functions at once using Doxygen groups. I would like the functions to share the same documentation as shown in the example [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup).

```
// @{
//! @brief Some documentation
int func1(void);
int func2(void);
// @}

// @{
//! @brief Some other documentation
int func3(void);
int func4(void);
// @}
```

However, when I run doxygen, *only the 2nd group* displays the @brief message in the HTML output. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a potential bug?

Note, I am *not* trying to nest groups, which the doxygen documentation says is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

The documentation to be factored out for each function group must *precede* the opening braces:

```
//! @brief Some documentation
// @{
int func1(void);
int func2(void);
// @}

//! @brief Some other documentation
// @{
int func3(void);
int func4(void);
// @}
```

Answer (score 4):

For this to work you [need to have](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC on in your config. And code specified as:

```
//@{
//! Same documentation for both members. Details ...
void func1InGroup1();
void func2InGroup1();
//@}
```

And if you want to name the grouped section:

```
//! @name Group name
//@{
//! Same documentation for both members. Details ...
void func1InGroup1();
void func2InGroup1();
//@}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: Doxygen is picky when it comes to whitespace. Make sure to use '//@{' and not '// @{'.

Comment: I tried reformatting all the @{ and @} grouping comments in one code file to make sure no spaces were being used. Unfortunately, same result...

Comment: Both stop to work since [this change](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/ef5af7618fbec3ac240e7a1099607d9ff2b3cc4f).